# None при вызове функции def

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

я хочу вызвать функцию def в print-те но у меня выводит None

```
import random


def fxe():
    enemies = ["гдето", "чтото", "ктото"]
    a = random.choice(enemies)
    print(a)


print('надо чтото вывести ', fxe())
```

сорян за такой код, это просто для примера

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вы `return` забыли

если функция ничего не возвращает, то считается, что она возвращает `None`

сделайте так:

```
def fxe():
    enemies = ["гдето", "чтото", "ктото"]
    a = random.choice(enemies)
    return a
```

P.S.

в гдето, чтото, когдато не хватает чего-то

Comment: большое тебе спасибо))